# How to kill a session using Apache Shiro on click of back or refresh button on browser?

Tags: apache, browser, shiro

I have been trying to kill a `session` on refresh or back button on browser using apache shiro for a web application but it seems i am not able to do it. Below is the code that i have tried. Any help much appreciated. Does shiro has those capabilities. How can it be achieved?

```
[main]    
    authc.loginUrl = /login.xhtml
    authc.usernameParam = USERNAME
    authc.passwordParam = USERPASSWORD
    authc.rememberMeParam = rememberMe
    user.loginUrl = /login.xhtml

    [users]
    admin=admin
    [urls]
    /login.xhtml = anon
```

Answer (score 0):

`[urls]
/login.xhtml = anon
/logout = logout`

logout is the default filter